# Add Casablanca REST to Qt-Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, casablanca

I'm trying to add Casablanca to a C++/Qt-Creator project on Linux in order to consume some Rest-Services. But the compiler always says "'cpprest/http_client.h' file not found".

Casablanca built without problems and the tests also run fine.

I tried adding the library as an external library with the "Add Library Wizard". The .pro file now contains:

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -    
L$$PWD/../casablanca/build.release/Binaries/release/ -lcpprest
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -   
L$$PWD/../casablanca/build.release/Binaries/debug/ -lcpprest
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../casablanca/build.release/Binaries/ -lcpprest

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../casablanca/build.release/Binaries
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../casablanca/build.release/Binaries
```

I would be glad if someone can help me.

Comment: Are Casablanca's include files stored in this directory `$$PWD/../casablanca/build.release/Binaries`? It looks like the path to binary files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed to extend the paths where the compiler should look for the include files. You might try to add the following statement to your .pro file:

```
unix:INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../casablanca/include
```